# Unable to get touch events on WP 8.1 Webview . jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8.1

I have a website that uses jquery mobile to detect touch interaction.
It works fine when I test it on the desktop, but when I try to use it embedded in a Windows Phone 8.1 WebView App, no touch events are triggered.
What am I missing here?

**-edit-**

ok here is some code I am using:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        jQuery(window).on("swipe", function (event) { NotifyApp("Test"); });
    });
</script>
```

The called NotifyApp function looks like this:

```
function NotifyApp(message) {
    if ((typeof (window.external) !== "undefined") && (typeof (window.external.notify) !== "undefined")) {
        window.external.notify(message);
    }
}
```

NotifApp() works as expected, the app is notified by this function when I call the it manually by a button.

Comment: you're missing code in your post.

Comment: I believe posting my code would not help the cause. It is a asp.net application that is pretty much cluttered. I am using jquery mobile to get touch events. It works as expected on desktop, but not on IE11 Mobile on Windows Phone 8.1. No touch events are fired on the phone

Comment: At least relevant code to touch events.

Comment: Ok I added the code that handles touch events

Comment: try wrapping your code in `$(document).on("pagecreate", function () { });` instead of `$(function () {});`.

Comment: That didn't help. I just checked something: $.mobile.support.touch returns false when I call it on the windows phone 8.1 emulator. Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59717/discussion-between-omar-and-buddybubble).